# NullPointer on loading strings into spinner

Tags: android, file, nullpointerexception, spinner

In the while statement, final2.add(read) is getting a nullpointer which leads me to believe that it is not reading the file correctly, so my question is the following am I obtaining the contents of the text file correctly?

```
@SuppressWarnings("null")
public void loadOpp() throws FileNotFoundException {
    File y = new File(getFilesDir()+File.separator+"Opponent.txt");
    FileReader x = new FileReader(y);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(x);
    String read;

    List<String> final2 = null;               
    try {
        while((read = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            final2.add(read);
          }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Spinner spinner= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, final2);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);        
}
```

logcat:

```
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.example.hoopstats/com.example.hoopstats.NewGame}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at com.example.hoopstats.NewGame.loadOpp(NewGame.java:67)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at com.example.hoopstats.NewGame.onCreate(NewGame.java:34)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize your final2 variable.

```
List<String> final2 = new List<String>();
```

Instead of

```
List<String> final2 = null;
```

There is no .add() method to null

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I missed that! I don't know what i was thinking when I was writing code, probably was distracted or something.

Comment: also its says that List cannot be instantiated

Comment: I always use ArrayList.  It can be added by importing java.util.ArrayList;  Then in your code do: ArrayList<String> final2 = new ArrayList<String>();

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `final2`. You declare it here

```
List<String> final2 = null;
```

just before the `loop` but you never initialize it before trying to call `add()` here

```
final2.add(read);
```

Change it to

```
List<String> final2 = new List<String>();
```

Also, for future reference, post logcat in your question when you have a crash. It almost always makes it easier for us to find where your problem is.

Comment: That has not fixed it though it did help remove a warning I supressed, here is logcat